# Organising code in X++ where all classes for the application are in one long classes list

Tags: class-design

I am just beginning to develop in Dynamics AX 2012, using X++ (my background is .Net). The development environment in the application stores all classes for the application in one long classes list.

I had started out creating several base classes and sub classing these to implement several features to read a file, parse and insert into the database using AX inbuilt functions.

However I have been asked to only use one class for the whole of the operation, to make it easy to copy between environments and to stop the classes list becoming full of classes.

Is this best practice when developing with X++ in Dynamics AX (2012 R2)?

Is there a better way to organise my code in this development environment?

(I can't believe that projects/areas were not implemented, or at least folders in the class list).

Comment: Really X++? Shouldn't be C++?

Comment: No really X++ - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx